# Google map area highlighting and appropriate zoom for "APPROXIMATE" areas

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

Is there any way of making it so that when use google map api and search for a location of the type "APPROXIMATE" it will automatically zoom out and highlight the approximate region in red -- exactly how it would work on google -- with the google map API v3? https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vHS7.png

On my site right now when you search Australia it makes the query into Northern Territory and just centers the map at a random point. I'm getting the user input of address and converting into lat/lng then sending that to the google map api. (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQvAR.png ) Please advise if there is another way, thanks.

I'm declaring the map canvas like this:

```
            map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $geo_latitude; ?>, <?php echo $geo_longitude; ?>),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                scrollwheel: false,
                 <?php echo(isMobile()) ? 'draggable: false' : ''; ?>
              });
```

Here is the function to parse what user wrote as location address into Lat/Long.

```
// convert address to lat/long
function get_lat_long($address){

    $address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address);

    $json = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=$region");
    $json = json_decode($json);

    $lat = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lat'};
    $long = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lng'};
    $types = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'types'};
    $location_type = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location_type'};

    if ( $types[0] == 'administrative_area_level_1' &&  $types[1] == 'political') {
        $types = "STATE";
    } elseif ( $types[0] == 'country' && $types[1] == 'political' ) {
        $types = "COUNTRY";
    } else {
        $types = "OTHER";
    }
    return $lat.','.$long.','.$types.','.$location_type;
}
```

Comment: I think yout main concern are country boundaries. They are available in FusionTables https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1uL8KJV0bMb7A8-SkrIe0ko2DMtSypHX52DatEE4#rows:id=1.
To set the appropriate zoom you should use map.setBounds(...)
As far as I know Google's geocoding service provides nothing more than approximate rectangular boundaries

Comment: I'm completely new to those fusion table thing. Is there any tutorials or guides on how to achieve what I need? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 Geocoder](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding), [it can contain a viewport and/or a bounds property in the result](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderGeometry) that will allow you to zoom your map so its bounds completely contains the result.

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    if (results[0].geometry.viewport) 
      map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
```